# Can I tell how much fees are sent in the UI with swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens?

Tags: uniswap

When swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens is implemented, does the Uniswap UI show how much fees are sent?

Answer (score 0):

The UI has no way of knowing the fee of a token. The one you see on the main interface is an expected output using standard erc20 code. Slippage is needed to cover this change for Fee-On-Transfer tokens. For everything, it's best to check the minimum out.